# Python multiprocessing - adding connections to a list

Tags: python, pipeline, python-multiprocessing

I'll be building multiple processes which have to communicate through multiple one-way pipes. For easy handling, I'd like to store the pipes in a list, like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Pipe

manager = Manager()    
pipes = manager.list()

for i in range(4):
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe(False)
    pipes.append([parent_conn, child_conn])

#... creating processes and passing pipes[i]s to them here
```

This, however, returns an error for the line of appending:

```
RemoteErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-dc004dda0358> in <module>()
     15     for i in range(matrixnum):
     16         parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe(False)
---> 17         pipes.append([parent_conn, child_conn])
     18 
     19     for i in range(matrixnum):

<string> in append(self, *args, **kwds)

/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.pyc in _callmethod(self, methodname, args, kwds)
    772             dispatch(conn, None, 'decref', (token.id,))
    773             return proxy
--> 774         raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
    775 
    776     def _getvalue(self):

RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 240, in serve_client
    request = recv()
TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add some more code, we do not even know which libraries you are using.

Comment: @Zafi Done, please let me know if you need something more! :)

Comment: you still didn't include the code that causes the problem

Comment: `pipes.append([parent_conn, child_conn])` is the line that causes the problem.

Comment: Why do you need the pipes in a manager list?

Comment: @lte__: For the sake of the example, just replace matrixnum with a real number or define it in the example

Comment: @Zafi Because I need it to be accessable for processes, and if I just pass a list as an argument to a process, it just creates a copy of the list.